# My file won't rewind properly in C++

Tags: c++

so my file won't rewind properly despite doing what my instructor told me to do. So i'm doing this.

```
inputFile.clear();
inputFile.seekg(0);
```

right before doing this.

```
while (inputFile >> name)
{
    if (sex == "M")
    {
        mCount++;
        mTotal = mTotal + score;
    }
    else if (sex == "F")
    {
        fCount++;
        fTotal = fTotal + score;
    }
    if (college == "CC")
    {
        ccCount++;
        ccTotal = ccTotal + score;
    }
    else if (college == "UN")
    {
        unCount++;
        unTotal = unTotal + score;
    }
    Count++;
    Total = Total + score;

}
```

but instead of doing what it should the file simply reads the last line instead of the entire .txt file and i don't know why.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What input do you give? Could you show us the rest of the code in action here?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `Count` at the end? It appears your `if ... else..` statements could be overly restrictive giving the appearance of nothing being read. But, nobody can help you unless you help us help you with [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the input is this 'cout << "Input file name: ";
 getline(cin, inputFileName);
 
 // Open the input file.
 inputFile.open(inputFileName);'
i know that part works because it is used earlier in the code and functions fine

Comment: By the way, you have a loop which read into `name`, but nowhere inside the loop do you use that `name` variable? You do use some totally unrelated variables, which you don't seem to be fetching from the file.

Comment: my count outputs 48, or 4 times the amount of inputs

Comment: the name variable is used in a different section of functional code. as long as the name variable exist the rest of the variables should as well if the user inputted them correctly

Comment: Other than saying you if statements are pointless because you don't read anything into any variable other than `name` I am not sure what we can do.

Comment: Outside of the loop, `name` is useless. It will only contain the value of the *last* name you read, which coincidentally seems to be your problem. Reading into `name` doesn't append or something, it *overwrites* the current contents of `name`. I suggest you take some time to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code line by line, then you can see the values of all variables and how they change (or *not* change) in the loop.

Comment: I also recommend you get [a few good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) to read, since you seem to have missed some basics about input and output using streams.